# How can I read the users computer make, model and serial number from inside MS Edge browser?

Tags: html, security, browser, microsoft-edge, privacy

Using Microsoft Edge web browser, under windows 10, how can I access the make/model and serial number of the computer that the browser is running on?

EDIT: This is currently happening, when logged into my live account I can see my make/model/serial, so it would help a project I am working on to be able to do this also.

Comment: I think this question must be best to be ask on Super User to provide best response. Because https://superuser.com/ talk about specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking and it contain a group of users enthusiast and experts on browsers and computer specifications. This site are more on programming. This may be reliable if your question is related on programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the latest browsers such as Chrome,Firefox,Microsoft Edge,they will automatically block such kind of requests when executing the script due to security reasons.

However,it is possible to get these hardware information using Internet Explorer since it supports ActiveX controls.ActiveX controls are Internet Explorer’s version of plug-ins.We can get these hardware information from Internet Explorer due to ActiveX controls security loopholes.
Here is more information on ActiveX controls: https://www.howtogeek.com/162282/what-activex-controls-are-and-why-theyre-dangerous/

We can exploit the security vulnerabilities of ActiveX controls to make this javascript work:

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML  PUBLIC  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
      <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta  name="GENERATOR"  content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
7.1">
            <meta  name="vs_targetSchema"
 content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
      <script  id=clientEventHandlersJS  language=javascript>
<!--

function Button1_onclick() {
      var locator = new ActiveXObject ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
      var service = locator.ConnectServer(".");
      var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
      var e = new Enumerator (properties);
      document.write("<table border=1>");
      for (;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext ())
      {
            var p = e.item ();
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.HostingBoard + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.Manufacturer + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.PoweredOn + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.Product + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.SerialNumber + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.Version + "</td>");
            document.write("</tr>");
      }
      document.write("</table>");
}

//-->
</script>
</head>
      <body>
            <INPUT  id="Button1"  type="button"  value="Button"
 name="Button1"  language=javascript  onclick="return Button1_onclick()">
      </body>
</html>
```

You will receive a warning message from IE but you should allow blocked contents for this to work.
This code will not work in any other browser,even Microsoft Edge.
Here is more information:https://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/1/

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A serial number is a unique, identifying number or group of numbers and letters assigned to an individual piece of hardware or software. A model specifies what type of computer are you using. **You can't identify them through any browser.**

Comment: But this is currently happening. I use a local account on my windows machine, and using my MS live account (unconnected to my pc) I can see this data, I have only ever logged into my MS account using Edge. I think Edge must be allowing this data to be accessed.

Comment: @Mar  Really? Where do you see the data.? Locally or through the browser?  This shouldn't happen! Your situation seems to be very confusing! What for are you needing the serial number? :)

Comment: I see it in my microsoft account under the devices tab! I figured if Edge supports this then it would be great for security to check the users serial number. https://account.microsoft.com/devices

Comment: @Mar The model shows up because the data was already uploaded to the server. (**Your computer physically sends the data. The server doesn't request the data**) . But Microsoft 'doesn't need' the serial number (Although it would have been a good idea to specifically identify a computer)

Comment: @Mar — I see that data in my Microsoft account … in Chrome … when I'm using a different computer … that doesn't run Windows.

Comment: So that means that Edge is connecting my Windows machine with my Live login via Edge, so it means Edge is providing extra data it would not provide to other sites or via other browsers.

Comment: @Mar No, you're account send the data. Microsoft Edge or other browser didn't.